# An example with pushout in $\mathbf{Set}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, equivalence-relations

From [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

> [image]

Why is in the sub-example with $Y\cap Z$, $(Y\sqcup Z)/{\sim}=Y\cup Z$? The text uses the undefined terminology ("to glue" a subset to a subset).

Also, the text claims that I an check that the square depicted is a pushout "by verifying the universal property or by using the formula just stated". What is "the formula just stated"? I don't see any formulas. As for verifying the universal property, as far as I understand, it will follow automatically from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303886/pushout-in-mathbf-set-proving-that-the-unique-map-is-well-defined) after one verifies that $(Y+Z)/{\sim}=Y\cup Z$, right?

Answer (score 1):

The 'formula just stated' refers to example 5.2.12, where it gives the general formula of a pushout in $\bf Set$.

Here we have $s:Y\cap Z\to Y$ and $t:Y\cap Z\to Z$ the inclusions, and thus the equivalence relation on $Y\sqcup Z$ is generated by $s(x) \sim t(x)$ for $x\in Y\cap Z$, that is, the $Y$-copy of $x$ is equivalent to ('*glued to*') the $Z$-copy of the same $x\in Y\cap Z$. 
No other elements of $Y\sqcup Z$ are affected by this relation, so that their equivalence classes are singletons.

The other suggested method is to verify the universal property right away for the union $Y\cup Z$. 
For that, consider two maps $Y\to W$ and $Z\to W$ which agree on $Y\cap Z$, and show they induce a unique map $Y\cup Z\to W$ (which makes the appropriate diagrams commute).

Combined with the first method, it also proves $Y\cup Z\ \cong \ Y\sqcup Z/\sim$.

Comment: Well, the unique map $\phi: Y\cup Z\to W$ is given by $\phi(t)=f_1(t)$ if $t\in Y$ and $\phi(t)=f_2(t)$ if $t\in Z$. How does this prove, together with your first paragraph, that $Y\cup Z=(Y\sqcup Z)/\sim$? And does the text suggest to prove  $Y\cup Z=(Y\sqcup Z)/\sim$ in this way?

Comment: The pushout is unique up to isomorphism in any category. By example 5.2.12, we get $Y\sqcup Z/\sim$ as a pushout. By the other method, we get $Y\cup Z$ is also a pushout. Hence they are isomorphic in $\bf Set$. And no, the text does not suggest that path to see they are in bijection with each other, it rather suggests to observe the direct identification of them.